# Airflow trigger dag with config which has list as a value

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I am trying to run a airflow dag through UI with config where i need to pass type(list) as value in key value input. something like this:
{
"input" : [{"date":"2022-01-01", "update": "1", "delete": "1"},{"date":"2022-01-02", "update": "0", "delete": "1"}]
}

I am reading it in my dag as script_input = " {{ dag_run.conf['input'] }} ". The problem is reading the config like this makes script_input as type str wherein I want it as list so that I can iterate through list in my script.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no solution for that, where the result of the jinja template will be always a string. To solve that, you can add a condition in your script:

```py
if isinstance(script_input, str):
    script_input = json.loads(script_input)
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked as per the requirement.